# Install Python extension to specific location

Tags: python, distutils

My project mix pure Python code, and Cython extensions for optimization and for linking with C libraries. I have one source tree for my Python project, and one for Cython and C code. My Cython extensions each have a setup.py file to build them. Actually, for each extension, I do the following:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
mv myext.so ../some/specific/place/
```

Is there a way to specify to distutils where to install my extension (if possible, using a relative path), instead of using `--inplace` followed by `mv`? Using `--prefix` option isn't good, since it creates a hierarchy of folders I don't need.

Comment: Could you put the content of your `setup.py` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found the answer! The option is -b (or --build_lib)

```
python setup.py build_ext -b ../some/specific/place/
```

Comment: Thanks - just to note it's `--build-lib` rather than `--build_lib`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [alternate installation](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#alternate-installation) functionnality of distutils which will allow you to remove the useless hierarchy folders.

Try something like this :

```
python setup.py install --home=../some/specific/place \
                        --install-purelib=. \
                        --install-platlib=.
```

Comment: Doing so install my extension in current directory, like with --inplace.